# How to pull and merge changes into current branch from master?

Tags: git

I am working on a branch called `create`. I have to pull the changes that are made into my branch. I already have done -

`git checkout master`

`git pull origin master`

and now I have to merge it. What's the way to merge it?

Comment: I don't get it. You want to merge `master` into `create` or `create` into `master`?

Comment: would you be clear on your question ? do you want to merge 'create' into 'master' or the opposite ?

Comment: I didn't do anything in the create branch. But my colleage have altered the master branch and they wanted me to pull the new changes into create.

Comment: In that case the answer from @nullpointer would be sufficient

Comment: As the last command should I use git merge master?

Comment: @mukhilsaravanan **git pull = git fetch + git merge**

Comment: @mukhilsaravanan please mark an answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 8):

Considering that you have updated the `master` on your local using

```
git checkout master && git pull origin master
```

You can pull the changes to `create` branch also using -

```
git checkout create && git pull origin master
```

***Edit*** - As suggested by @Zarwan, rebase is also another option. For details on when to use which, please look into [When do you use git rebase instead of git merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge)

Comment: If you follow the above commands, you won't have to `merge` explicitly but resolve conflicts if there be any. `git commit` and `git push origin create` should work fine to push your code then.

Comment: will git merge master, pull all the changes into create branch? I am new to comman line

Comment: @mukhilsaravanan If it helped, do mark it as an answer for others to benefit from.

Answer (score 6):

It is recommended to rebase your feature branch with master rather than merge it. Details below

**rebase** - if you are still working on your feature branch `create`, then rebase your feature branch to `master`. This allows you to work on your branch with the latest version of `master` as if you've just branched off your master.

```
git checkout create
git rebase master
```

**merge** - use it when you finish your task on your feature branch and want to merge it to other branches. For example, when you finish your work on `create` branch and want to merge it with `master`.

```
git checkout master
git merge create
git push origin master
```

This operation also generates a merge commit on your `master` branch.

Comment: Why is it recommended to rebase rather than merge?

Comment: @Matthias rebasing will result a linear history of your commits, making it easier to navigate the changes your codebase has gone through over time.

Answer (score 2):

`git checkout create`

`git rebase origin master`

This will take the changes on your branch and apply them on top of the current master branch, and your branch will be updated to point to the result. In other words, `master` will be merged into `create`.